# Multiple Join in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following query in TSQL

```
select * from users 
inner join linkUserPhoneNumber on users.UserId = linkUserPhoneNumber.UserId
INNER JOIN PhoneNumber ON PhoneNumber.PhoneNumberId =
    linkUserPhoneNumber.PhoneNumberId
    where UserName = 'superuser' and password ='password'
```

I have the following query in Entity Framework

```
var query = (from u in myEntities.Users
  join link in myEntities.linkUserPhoneNumbers on u.UserId equals link.UserId 
  join p in myEntities.PhoneNumbers on p.PhoneNumberId equals link.PhoneNumberId
  where u.UserName == Username && u.Password == Password
  select u).ToList();
```

When I try to compile it, I get

> Error  3   The name 'p' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.
>   Error   4   The name 'link' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.

Comment: I think you copy pasted, so I can see an 'eqals' that maybe is 'equals'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exactly what the error is saying

```
p.PhoneNumberId equals link.PhoneNumberId
```

should be

```
link.PhoneNumberId equals p.PhoneNumberId
```

Full code

```
var query = (from u in myEntities.Users
  join link in myEntities.linkUserPhoneNumbers on u.UserId equals link.UserId 
  join p in myEntities.PhoneNumbers on link.PhoneNumberId equals p.PhoneNumberId
  where u.UserName == Username && u.Password == Password
  select u).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, that was simple enough. I guess ive been doing TSQL for so long I did'nt notice. Thanks again